Why custom multiselection element is not available after I selected item?
I am working on a Laravel 10 site. Using docs at https://dev.to/koossaayy/laravel-livewire-multiple-selection-with-virtual-select-1f87, I try to make multiselection. I made it with some changes in the code.
In component:
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Admin;

use App\Models\Permission;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Livewire\Component;

class UsersPermissionsEditor extends Component
{
    public $selectedPermissions= [];
    public $permissionsListing= [];

    public function render()
    {
        $this->permissionsListing = Permission::query()->get()/*->pluck('name', 'id')*/
            ->map(function ($selectedPermissionItem) {
                return ['id' => $selectedPermissionItem->id, 'label' => Str::replace('_', ' ', Str::title($selectedPermissionItem->name))];
            })
        ->toArray();
        return view('livewire.admin.users-permissions-editor');
    }
}

and in Blade:
<div class="admin_page_container" id="users_permissions_editor_admin_page_container">
    <div class="editor_listing_wrapper_bix_width" x-data="adminUsersPermissionsEditorComponent()"
         x-init="[onAdminUsersPermissionsEditorComponentInit() ]" x-cloak>

        $selectedPermissions::{{ print_r($selectedPermissions, true) }}

        <input id="permissionsListing" name="permissionsListing" value="add permissionsListing TEST">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/virtual-select-plugin@1.0.39/dist/virtual-select.min.js"
                integrity="sha256-Gsn2XyJGdUeHy0r4gaP1mJy1JkLiIWY6g6hJhV5UrIw=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet"
              href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/virtual-select-plugin@1.0.39/dist/virtual-select.min.css"
              integrity="sha256-KqTuc/vUgQsb5EMyyxWf62qYinMUXDpWELyNx+cCUr0=" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <div>
             AAAAA<div id="permissions"></div>BBB
            <script>

                function adminUsersPermissionsEditorComponent() {
                    console.log('adminUsersPermissionsEditorComponent::')

                    return {
                        fillUsersPermissions: function () {
                            var permissionsListing = @json($permissionsListing)

                                VirtualSelect.init({
                                    ele: '#permissions',
                                    multiple: true,
                                    options: permissionsListing,
                                });
                            let selectedPermissions = document.querySelector('#permissions');
                            selectedPermissions.addEventListener('change', () => {
                                let data = selectedPermissions.value;
                                @this.set('selectedPermissions', data);
                            });
                        },



                        onAdminUsersPermissionsEditorComponentInit: function () {
                        },


                    }
                }


            </script>

        </div>
    </div>

I see available multiselection element, but when I click on one of elements the multiselection element is not visible at all.
What I see in browsers console:

How that can be fixed?
"laravel/framework": "^10.48.4",
"livewire/livewire": "^3.4.9",


Are you forced to use standard javascript? Are you using Alpine at all? I have this working using Livewire and Alpine if that would help I can post the code here.

Yes, I have installed Alpinejs from the start. Please post working code

The main problem is that every time @this.set('selectedPermissions',.... is applied a call to the backend is done, so the DOM is redrawn and the changes and the event listeners applied by VirtualSelect are lost.
A simple fix is to add a wire:ignore to the <div> used by VirtualSelect, in this way Livewire will not alter the content of that <div>:
class UsersPermissionsEditor extends Component
{
    public $selectedPermissions = [1, 3];
    public $permissionsListing = [];


    public function render()
    {
        $this->permissionsListing = Permission::query()
                  ->get(['id', 'name'])
                  ->map(function ($selectedPermissionItem) {
                            return ['value' => $selectedPermissionItem->id,
                                    'label' => Str::replace('_', ' ', Str::title($selectedPermissionItem->name))
                            ];
        })->toArray();

        return view('livewire.admin.users-permissions-editor');
    }
}

<div class="admin_page_container" id="users_permissions_editor_admin_page_container">

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/virtual-select-plugin@1.0.39/dist/virtual-select.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-Gsn2XyJGdUeHy0r4gaP1mJy1JkLiIWY6g6hJhV5UrIw=" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>

    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/virtual-select-plugin@1.0.39/dist/virtual-select.min.css"
          integrity="sha256-KqTuc/vUgQsb5EMyyxWf62qYinMUXDpWELyNx+cCUr0=" crossorigin="anonymous"
    >

    <div class="editor_listing_wrapper_bix_width"
         x-data="adminUsersPermissionsEditorComponent('permissions')"
         x-cloak
    >
        <div>

            <div wire:ignore id="permissions"></div>

        </div>

    </div>

    selectedPermissions: {{ implode(', ', $selectedPermissions) }}

</div>

<script>

    function adminUsersPermissionsEditorComponent(element) {

        return {

            init: function () {

                VirtualSelect.init({

                    ele: "#" + element,
                    multiple: true,
                    options: @json($permissionsListing), 
                    selectedValue: @json($selectedPermissions) 
                });

                document.getElementById(element).addEventListener("change", function () {

                    // console.log (this.value);
                    @this.set("selectedPermissions", this.value);
                });
            },
        }
    }

</script>

In this example I've applied some changes:

in the class the map() must return value not id
in the view x-init is not needed: I've replaced the name of the fillUsersPermissions() function with init() to allow it's auto-execution
I parameterized the id of the <div> affected by VirtualSelect
I've added a display of the $selectedPermissions variable for debugging


Thanks! That helped, but how to set default values selected ? I tried set values in $selectedPermissions - but did not help - default no items are selected

To preselect values you can pass the selectedValue parameter when VirtualSelect is initialized. I have modified my example to show this. The documentatin is here

Here is a different version using Tailwind CSS, Livewire and Alpine I created to allow multiple roles to be selected for a user.
<div x-data="{ open: false, selectedRoles: @entangle('selectedRoles') }" class="relative">
    <x-label for="roles" required value="{{ __('Role(s)') }}" />
    <div class="relative mt-2">
        <button @click="open = !open" type="button" class="relative w-full cursor-default rounded-md bg-white py-1.5 pl-3 pr-10 text-left text-gray-900 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-sky-600 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-expanded="true" aria-labelledby="listbox-label">
            <span class="block truncate" x-text="selectedRoles.length > 0 ? `${selectedRoles.length} role${selectedRoles.length > 1 ? 's' : ''} selected` : '{{ __('Select Roles') }}'">{{ __('Select Roles') }}</span>
            <span class="pointer-events-none absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-2">
                <svg class="h-5 w-5 text-gray-400" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10 3a.75.75 0 01.55.24l3.25 3.5a.75.75 0 11-1.1 1.02L10 4.852 7.3 7.76a.75.75 0 01-1.1-1.02l3.25-3.5A.75.75 0 0110 3zm-3.76 9.2a.75.75 0 011.06.04l2.7 2.908 2.7-2.908a.75.75 0 111.1 1.02l-3.25 3.5a.75.75 0 01-1.1 0l-3.25-3.5a.75.75 0 01.04-1.06z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                </svg>
            </span>
        </button>

        <ul x-show="open" @click.away="open = false" x-cloak class="absolute z-10 mt-1 max-h-60 w-full overflow-auto rounded-md bg-white py-1 text-base shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none sm:text-sm" tabindex="-1">
            @foreach($roles as $role)
                <li x-bind:class="selectedRoles.includes('{{ $role->name }}') ? 'bg-gray-50' : ''" @click="selectedRoles.includes('{{ $role->name }}') ? selectedRoles = selectedRoles.filter(name => name !== '{{ $role->name }}') : selectedRoles.push('{{ $role->name }}')" class="text-gray-900 relative cursor-default select-none py-2 pl-3 pr-9">
                <span x-bind:class="selectedRoles.includes('{{ $role->name }}') ? 'font-semibold text-sky-800' : 'font-normal'" class="block truncate">
                    {{ $role->name }}
                </span>
                    <!-- Display a checkmark if the role is selected -->
                    <span x-show="selectedRoles.includes('{{ $role->name }}')" class="text-sky-600 absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-4">
                        <svg class="h-5 w-5" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M16.704 4.153a.75.75 0 01.143 1.052l-8 10.5a.75.75 0 01-1.127.075l-4.5-4.5a.75.75 0 011.06-1.06l3.894 3.893 7.48-9.817a.75.75 0 011.05-.143z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                        </svg>
                    </span>
                </li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

In your Livewire component:
public $selectedRoles = [];

public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.componenet', [
        'roles' => Role::all()
    ]);
}

To prefill the roles, for instance if you are editing, you would load the selected roles via mount():
public $selectedRoles = [];

public function mount(): void
{
    $this->selectedRoles = $this->user->getRoleNames();
}

Output:

If you're using the Tall stcak there will be no need to import any additional JS libraries to run the code above.
Dropdown will show a checkmark next to the selected items and the number of selected items in the field.
